# Can we get the Directory's Modified time and size i.e. stats?

Tags: php

Can we get the Directory's Modified time and size i.e. stats in php? How?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. You can make use of [stat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) function

```
$stat = stat('\path\to\directory');
echo 'Modification time: ' . $stat['mtime']; // will show unix time stamp.
echo 'Size: ' . $stat['size']; // in bytes.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the modified time with [`filemtime`](http://php.net/filemtime) or [`SplFileInfo::getMTime`](http://php.net/splfileinfo.getmtime).

As for getting the size of the directory, do you mean the file size of all of the contents within it (might sound like a silly question, *size* is ambiguous)?

If you are wanting just the recorded 'filesize' of the directory then [`filesize`](http://php.net/filesize) or [`SplFileInfo::getSize`](http://php.net/splfileinfo.getsize) should suffice.

```
$dir = new SplFileInfo('path/to/dir');
printf(
    "Directory modified time is %s and size is %d bytes.", 
    date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $dir->getMTime()),
    $dir->getSize()
);
```

Answer (score 5):

For me using `filemtime` worked just fine.

#### Example

```
<?php

$path_to_file = '/tmp/';
echo filemtime($path_to_file); // 1380387841
```

Even though it is called "file mtime" it works for directories, too.

#### Caveat / Gotcha

Make sure the file or directory you are checking exists otherwise you'll get something like:

> filemtime(): stat failed for /asdfasdfasdf in test.php on line 3

Possible fixes include something 'proper':

```
$path = '/tmp/';
$mtime = file_exists($path)?filemtime($path):'';
```

And something less verbose but hacky by using the error suppression operator (`@`):

```
$path = '/tmp/';
$mtime = @filemtime($path);
```

#### From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

## filemtime()

> int **filemtime** ( string **$filename** )
>
> This function returns the time when the data blocks of a file were being written to, that is, the time when the content of the file was changed.