# how to get the last modified of a directory under site/default/files

Tags: php, drupal

I have tried to use the php method stat and I have tried filectime but I cannot get any date for the directories .  I am doing this with php in a custom drupal 8 module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773009/can-we-get-the-directorys-modified-time-and-size-i-e-stats this could help you.

Comment: that is what I tried but not getting any results .  does this work on php7?